# Как сделать ромб на чистом css?

Tags: html, css

Можете подсказать как сделать бордерами ромб? Пробовал использовать как SVG, но такой вариант не подходит, т.к есть проблемы с адаптивом.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [css+ромб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bcss%5d%20%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.box {
  background: 
  linear-gradient(to top right, transparent calc(49.5% - 3px), #000 calc(49.5% - 2px), #000 49.5%, transparent 50%) top right, 
  linear-gradient(to top left, transparent calc(49.5% - 3px), #000 calc(49.5% - 2px), #000 49.5%, transparent 50%) top left, 
  linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent calc(49.5% - 3px), #000 calc(49.5% - 2px), #000 49.5%, transparent 50%) bottom right, 
  linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent calc(49.5% - 3px), #000 calc(49.5% - 2px), #000 49.5%, transparent 50%) bottom left;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 220px;
  height: 420px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 57.73%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Ваш текст
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.block {
  --border: 2px solid black;
  --size: 70px;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  margin: calc(var(--size) / 4);
  margin-top: calc(var(--size) / 1.5);
  transform: scaleY(1.5);
}

.block::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: var(--border);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
</div>
```